# Laravel: Set up Laravel vhost

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, laravel

Hi so I'm setting up Laravel, but it keeps redirecting to the "Whoops something went wrong page"

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/myfolder/public"
     ServerName ron@gmail.com
     ServerAlias l1.mysite.com
     <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/laravel/laravel/public">
     AllowOverride All
     Order Allow,Deny
     Allow from all
     Require all granted
     </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

I have the l1.mysite.com in my hosts file as well. And in my httpd.conf file, "LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so" is included (without #) and my httpd-vhosts.conf is included as well. Any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: Have you ran `php composer install/update`?

Comment: `ServerName` should be l1.mysite.com, remove `ServerAlias`, and then update your question with the exact error that you're seeing..

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting `Whoops: Something went wrong`, that means PHP is actually doing it's thing correctly, and your vhost might not be the issue. What's the error message you get?

You likely need to:

1. Make sure you've installed dependencies (as noted in comments  `composer install` or `composer update`
2. Ensure `app/storage` directory (and sub directories) are writable by PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Set debug in your app.php to true that is open  app/config/app.php and change the value of debug => true. You would have an idea what's really wrong.