# What is a Laravel vhost file and what is it for?

Tags: php, frameworks, laravel, laravel-4

A mate of mine has told me to look up Laravel vhost file. I assume it is so that Apache can render the website for me before I view it or something, but to be totally honest I am baffled.

What is this vhost file for? How do I get it to work?

Comment: I suspect it's an [Apache vhost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/) file - it creates a new Apache virtual host for a web site. This means you can run `http://myblog/` and `http://mylaravelapp/` in a single Apache instance, for example. (By the way, I recommend doing a thorough web search prior to asking questions - the docs for this one can be found quite readily via "[apache vhost](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=apache+vhost)").

Comment: Thank you, as you can see I have searched for laravel vhost, and instead will now search for apache vhost. Many thanks.

Comment: No problem. A search for that [got me this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338126/laravel-set-up-laravel-vhost), which should be useful.

Answer (score 2):

There is no official Laravel VHost file, just an [official Laravel .htaccess file](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess):

You going to see a lot of vhosts files around the Internet, but, basically what your vhost file should have is a pointer to the /public folder, so it should look something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yourdomain.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www/yourdomain/public

    <Directory /var/www/yourdomain>
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```